# Beginner: Fastest way to cast/copy byte() into single()

Tags: vb.net, byte, casting, ctype

I've got a byte() array returned as result of directx sound capture, but for other parts of my program I want to treat the results as single(). Is trundling down the array item by item the fastest way of doing it or is there a clever way to do it ?

The code that gets it is

```
CType(Me._applicationBuffer.Read(Me._nextCaptureOffset, GetType(Byte), LockFlag.None, LockSize), Byte())
```

which creates the byte array, can Ctype handle single ? (note, I can't figure out a way to  do it!)

Answer (score 1):

```
public float[] ByteArrayToFloatArray(byte[] byteArray)
{
    float[] floatArray = new float[byteArray.Length / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.Length; i++)
    {
        floatArray[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(byteArray, i * 4);
    }
    return floatArray;
}
```

The fastest way to do this (in terms of performance as opposed to how long it takes to write) would probably be to use the [CopyMemory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/netcopymemorysample.aspx) API call.

Comment: might need to add a check to make sure bytearray.Length % 4 == 0 ?

Comment: His byte array is from audio data, so the length will probably often not be a multiple of 4.

Comment: It just occurred to me that if his data is stereo, then it will probably always be a multiple of 4.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytearray, 0);
```

In VB (I think):

```
Dim single s;
s = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytearray, 0);
```

Comment: That's not what he's asking.

Also, VB doesn't use a semicolon! I make that mistake whenever I'm forced to touch VB ;-)